# Are there good reasons not to target Flash 10 for a browser-based game?

Tags: flash, rich-internet-application

There's clearly a bunch of new stuff in Flash 10, I'm seeing a bunch in the `Graphics` class so far. Struggling a bit to reconcile it with what I know already but it looks useful - render lists and 3D transforms, etc - however I wondered if there are good arguments for targeting Flash 9 since I can definitely manage without all the new stuff I don't know. Like support on non-Windows devices, wide adoption of Flash 9 Vs 10, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1% more people have flash player 9 and below, than have flash player 10.
http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html

It's a shame that these figures aren't broken down further, but you can assume that by publishing for player 10, at most, 1% more people will have to upgrade than if you targeted player 9.

As well as new classes being available, player 10 also had a lot of speed improvements.

To answer your question, none that I can think of :)

Comment: That's an amazing penetration in such a short time. How on earth did they manage it... and does it mean we can assume 10.1 will be at the same level in just a few months? However I do wonder how this data treats mobile devices and games consoles that have some special bespoke Flash player?

Comment: When a new version is released, people running on Windows get prompted to update and Google's Chrome silently auto-updates the Flash Player, as it is pre-installed in it.

Comment: I don't think that games consoles and and mobile devices have bespoke flash players. I believe they are all using 10.1, unless they are using FlashLite.

Comment: I also believe flash player 10 was released late 2008.